# rsync not working after revoking public access aws ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rsync

I have a setup where I need to copy a files from 1 ec2 instance to another instance using rsync, I used following command which worked fine

```
rsync -ave 'ssh -i certs/cert.pem' /var/www/html/uploads/2018/9/6/instagram.png ubuntu@[ec2-instance-IP]:/var/www/html/uploads/2018/9/6/
```

This command was running and I could see the files on both server. Later I revoked the public access to make the servers more secure but now the files are not copying to another server. It seems the command is not working now and giving following error

```
ssh: connect to host IP port 22: Connection timed out
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.1]
```

I am able to connect to ftp and putty using private ips with same certificate file so not sure what is the issue.

Can someone help me out to resolve the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the old "ssh login hangs without a network (DNS)" problem. Make sure `UseDNS no` is set in the destination's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and restart the sshd service if needed.

Comment: its missing in sshd_config file so should I add it there ? also this needs to be changed in ssh_config file as well or just in sshd_config file ?

Comment: Yes, add `UseDNS no` below the commented out `# UseDNS yes` and restart the ssh service

Comment: its not working and giving same error :(

Comment: Try also sshing to the destination box **by IP** and see if that works.